# Troubleshooting Unexpected "spectre v2 mitigation" Error in VirtualBox Kali Linux Setup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kali-linux, virtualbox

I've been using Kali Linux in VirtualBox without any issues until today. Unexpectedly, I received the following error message:

"warning: spectre v2 mitigation leaves cpu vulnerable to retbleed attacks, data leaks possible!"

I want to emphasize that I haven't made any changes to the VM settings, Kali Linux installation, or related files. Everything was working fine just yesterday, and I didn't delete any ISO files or components of the Kali Linux setup.

I've been running this setup:

- Host: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.3086]
- VirtualBox: 7.0.10
- Kali Linux: 2022.1
- CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-9400 CPU @ 2.90GHz

Despite investigating, no correlated updates were found. I'm now seeking insights into why this error suddenly emerged, and I'm eager to discover any steps I can take to address it. My primary focus is on maintaining both the security and stability of my setup, while also understanding the root cause of this issue.

Your assistance and expertise are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: that warning has little to do with the kernel panic - but the fact that this message is new to you does suggest something has changed (kernel upgrade?)

Comment: This is similar to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/755130/86440 (but not a duplicate, at least not given the current state of both questions).

Comment: @JaromandaX it could also be that they’ve never seen the message before because they’ve never seen the boot message before, and they are seeing them now because of the kernel panic.

Comment: this is different unix.stackexchange.com/q/755130/86440

Comment: The actual cause of the kernel panic is that the kernel was **unable to mount the root filesystem**.  It says this on the second line and again on the last line (the spectre mitigation warning is unrelated).  Did you add or remove any virtual drives to the VM?  Did you delete or somehow corrupt the virtual disk image file? (check if the VDI still exists and is approximately the expected size).  Are you running virtualbox as a different user?  Or change the VDI's ownership or access rules?